# Faster way to pull specific data from NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array full of NSObjects I created called "Questions".
One property of each Question is which level it belongs to.
If the user has chosen to play level 2, I want to get all the Questions that have a .level property of 2. Right now I am looping through all the questions to find the matches, but this is taking ~2 seconds on an iPad 3 / new iPad device. Is there a faster way of dealing with a situation like this?

```
int goThrough = 0;    
do {
      Question *currentQuestion = [allQs objectAtIndex:(goThrough)];

      if (currentQuestion.level == levelChosen) {
             [questions addObject:currentQuestion];
      }
      goThrough++;
    } while (goThrough < [allQs count]);
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you would have to have a __boat load__ of questions for a loop over them to take 2 seconds.  I would look elsewhere for your delay.  I would also perhaps cache the filtered list.  I would also suggest familiarity with `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]`.

Comment: The thing you seek is known as a data base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to organize the questions by level on a regular basis, then why not keep all of the questions organized by level. Create a dictionary of arrays. Each key if the level and each array is the list of questions for that level. You do this once and it becomes trivial to get the questions for a level.

Comment: Indeed, altering your design to avoid repeatedly filtering the objects is going to be faster than any optimized method of filtering them (assuming the list of questions is static.) This seems like a better way than our suggestions to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock. (voted)

Comment: @DuncanC Even if the list isn't static. As a new question gets added, you simply add it to the proper sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the NSArray method enumerateObjectsUsingBlock or one of it's variants. There are even variants that will loop through the array elements concurrently. You'd probably need to use a lock to add elements to your questions array however, since I doubt if NSMutableArray's addObject method is thread-safe.

You should probably test a non-concurrent version against a concurrent version with locking to see which is faster. Which approach is faster would depend on how many of the objects in the allQs array belong to the current level. If only a few belong, the code that asserts a lock won't fire very often, and the benefit of concurrency will outweigh the time penalty of asserting a lock. If most of the objects in the allQs array match the chosen level, code will end up spending a lot of time asserting locks, and the concurrent threads will still waiting for other threads to release a lock.

Modified code might look something like this:

single-threaded version:

```
[allQs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
   ^(Question *currentQuestion, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
   {
     if (currentQuestion.level == levelChosen)
       [questions addObject:currentQuestion];
   }
];
```

Concurrent version:

```
[allQs enumerateObjectsWithOptions:
     NSEnumerationConcurrent
   usingBlock:
   ^(Question *currentQuestion, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
   {
     if (currentQuestion.level == levelChosen)
       @synchronized
       {
         [questions addObject:currentQuestion];
       }
   }
];
```

Actually, now that I think about it, you would likely get still faster performance by first doing a concurrent pass on the array using indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest. In that pass you'd build an NSIndexSet of all the objects that match the current level. Then in one pass you'd extract those elements into another array:

```
NSIndexSet *questionIndexes = [allQs indexesOfObjectsWithOptions: NSEnumerationConcurrent        
  usingBlock:
  ^(Question *currentQuestion, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
  {
    return (currentQuestion.level == levelChosen)
  }
];
questions = [allQs objectsAtIndexes: questionIndexes];
```

Another poster pointed out that you are better off breaking up your arrays of questions up by level in advance. If that works with your program flow it's better, since not filtering your array at all will always be faster than the most highly optimized filtering code.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use fast enumeration (which, unless you intend on mutating the objects is the fastest way to enumerate a collection).  Something like this:

```
for (Question *thisQuestion in allQs) {
    if (thisQuestion.level == levelChosen) 
        [questions addObject:thisQuestion];
    }
}
```

Since you are not mutating the collection you are iterating through (`allQs`), this would work fine and be faster than using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`.  If you need the index of the array you are iterating through (`allQs`), then use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`.

Comment: Is for...in looping faster than single-threaded enumerateObjectsUsingBlock? I've wondered about that. Have you timed this yourself, or is the performance difference documented somewhere?

Comment: My experiences have shown slightly faster results with Fast Enum, and this post by Matt Thompson backs that up.  http://nshipster.com/enumerators/  That said, I think the speed advantage is slight in most cases (maybe even in some), and enumerateObjectsUsingBlock does give one the advantage of getting the index for free.  I typically use for-in just because it is so simple (unless I need the index for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to a mac at the moment but you can give a try to this:

```
[allQs  enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
  Question *currentQuestion = [allQs objectAtIndex:index];
  if (currentQuestion.level == levelChosen) {
    [questions addObject:currentQuestion];
  }
}
```

This will use all the cores of your device so it can be twice as fast

Comment: Note that adding objects to a mutable array is not thread safe, so you would have to protect `[questions addObject:currentQuestion]` by some synchronization mechanism (which makes everything slow again).

Comment: Astri, Martin is right. You can't add objects to a mutable array from multiple threads concurrently. See my post for several different solutions. I think the last one, using a concurrent call to indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock: is probably fastest, since it avoids mutating the array from a background thread. It also has the advantage that it isn't making a mutable array bigger by one item at a time, which is also slow.  This discussion is interesting and educational, but Maddy is right that it's really better to refractor to break up the data by levels once at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple answer that seems to be missing. If you want to filter the objects of an array to only have certain ones left, `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` is what you would want. It can be done exceptionally simply.

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(Question *aQuestion, NSDictionary *bindings){
    return (aQuestion.level==2);
}];
NSArray *filteredArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Comment: The question isn't about making it simple, it is about making it faster. Using a predicate will be much slower than a purpose built array.

Comment: Creating a predicate with `-predicatWithFormat:` is expensive. Using one is the same as iterating over the entire array with enumeration. It may actually be faster because the frameworks are good at taking advantage of the device hardware for array filtering.